# Keystone correction

Tags: windows, display

We're using a beamer to project information onto a wall. Unfortunately the built-in hardware keystone correction cannot correct it in that amount needed to display a nice picture.

Until now, we take a screenshot of what we want to display, apply a perspective to it and then use the result to project with the beamer.

Since we want to change the content more often, I would like to have a software that takes the screen content and applies that software keystone correction automatically.

That software

- must work on Windows (10 at least)
- may cost up to 50 €
- if technically not otherwise possible, can mirror screen 1 to screen 2
- may only update a few times per second (no full 60 Hz needed)